# I need to setup the friendly urls for a website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to make friendly urls for this website: https://superbackings.com. The trouble is when you place a search, the url appears this way https://superbackings.com/?search=bon+jovi
But I need the urls shown this way https://superbackings.com/backing-tracks/bon-jovi

I'm trying everything and nothing is working. Here is the code content.

```
<div class="buscador">
<form class="mb-3 form-inline" action="">
<input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="search your song" name="search" value="<?php echo $search ?>"> <br> <br>
<button class="btn btn-dark ">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Those rewrite rules have no effect on how your site _generates_ URLs. They just rewrite _incoming requests_ to the right place. Whatever search logic you have needs to built URLs the way you want.

Comment: What I need to know is how to change this 
/backing-tracks?search=bon+jovi . into this 
/backing-tracks/search/bon+jovi

As you can see the trouble is the ?search

Comment: And I'm telling you that you're looking in the wrong place. The Apache configuration you've shown here has nothing to do with that. You need to look at the code that runs when you click the search button. Feel free to [edit] your question and show that to us.

Comment: Ok! I will show you the php code..

Comment: Chris, this is the PHP that call the search and the pagination.

Comment: Is the URL `https://superbackings.com/?search=bon+jovi` generated by a GET form? If so, you could redirect from that to the search URL that you want (perhaps by detecting if the `search` query string value is populated).